# WATIN simulating right button click in Firefox

Tags: firefox, watin

I use the following code to simulate right button click

NameValueCollection eventProperties = new NameValueCollection();
eventProperties.Add("button", "2");
box.FireEvent("onmousedown", eventProperties);

they work well in IE, but does not work in Firefox, Firefox still recognize the click as left (0) button button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've come up against this as well.  It will probably be seen to within WatiN but I did find a workaround.

The workaround is not great as it involves a local variable to give the tests a hook.  Test sets variable, and then right click checking code either works to

```
button == 2 || testHook == 1
```

Not pretty but it seems like a tricky one until the framework is updated.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to solve this for FireFox [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990905/watin-fireevent-not-passing-event-properties-in-firefox/4998225#4998225). This needs to be fixed in WatiN though.

Jeroen