# MbUnit Gallio WatiN Right-Click Testing on a link

Tags: watin, right-click, mbunit, gallio

I want to test right click on a link by using MbUnit, Gallio and WatiN. Currently I can not see what is the way to do that. It seems that there is no method for right click which I can call from the framework. I am sure that there is a workaround, which I was not able to find currently.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In WatiN, you might need to fire event directly, such as

```
myElement.FireEvent("oncontextmenu")
```

Also look at: 
[WatiN FireEvent not passing event properties in FireFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990905/watin-fireevent-not-passing-event-properties-in-firefox)

In selenium WebDriver, you can Use the Actions class. 
In C#,

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("LinkText"));
Actions actioner = new Actions(driver);
actioner.MoveToElement(elem).ContextClick(elem).Perform();
```